# Help with a natural deduction proof

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Does anyone have any idea how to prove this?

```
/[P ⊃ (Q ⊃ R)] ⊃ [(P ⊃ Q) ⊃ (P ⊃ R)]
```

So far I have

```
1' P ⊃ (Q ⊃ R)         AcP

 2' P ⊃ Q              AcP

  3' ~P                AIP
```

Thanks

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: On 3', I would instead just assume $P$ and use the two previous hypothesis to eventually reach $R$ in the subproof that starts with $P$.

Comment: Did you understand my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Standard notation is "$\to$" for "implies" because "$\supset$" denotes "[strict] superset". Also, "$\neg$" is standard for "not".

> If $P \to ( Q \to R )$:
>
> If $P \to Q$:
>
> If $P$:
>
> $Q \to R$.
>
> $Q$.
>
> $R$.
>
> $\cdots$

I'll leave you to fill in the final steps and the justification for each step.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a completed proof with justifications. The proof checker and an associated text are cited in the links below:

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/